# How to define samples in caret package?

Tags: r, random-forest, caret

I am using the **caret** package and need to train a random forest, where only certain samples should be in the held-out set. I want to define the sampling for each tree in the random forest, for say 100 tress. How can I do this? What does the number of re-sample iteration even mean (is it the same as the number of trees)?

I have tried the following but for some reason it is taking an unusual long time to train, so I am not certain whether it is correct or not:

```
library(caret)
temp.resample_in <- createResample(training_index, times=100)  
temp.resample_out <- foreach (temp.ind = 1:length(temp.resample_in) {
   setdiff(training_index, temp.resample_in[[temp.ind]])
}

fitControl <- trainControl(
method = "oob",
number = 100,
classProbs = TRUE,         
allowParallel = TRUE,
summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
index = temp.resample_in, 
indexOut = temp.resample_out) 

rf.model <- train(x = data, method = "rf"
                ,  trControl = fitControl                   
                , verbose = TRUE
                , metric = "ROC")
```

Answer (score 1):

> only certain samples should be in the held-out set

The held-out set inside of random forest? I don't think you can do that.

`trainControl` can let you specify what gets held out when you use cross-validation or bootstrapping (but the bootstrapping outside of random forests). You are using `method = "oob"` so you aren't intending on doing any external resampling but since you use `index` it probably is doing 100 iterations (which is why it is taking so long).

You would need to interact directly with the `randomForest` function but I don't think it give you that level of control.

Max